# Error in the class of random forest

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm feeding a new set of data to the Random forest prediction model and encounter this error:

> Error in checkData(oldData, RET) : 
>     Classes of new data do not match original data

Here's the code:

```
fit1 <- cforest((b == 'three')~   affect+ certain+ negemo+ future+swear+sad
            +negate+ppron+sexual+death + filler+leisure + conj+ funct + i
            +future + past + bio + body+cause + cogmech + death +
                    discrep + future +incl + motion + quant + sad + tentat + excl+insight +percept +posemo
            +ppron +quant + relativ + space + article + age + s_all + s_sad + gender 
            , data = trainset1, 
            controls=cforest_unbiased(ntree=500, mtry= 1))

testset2$pre_swl<-predict(fit1, newdata=testset2 , type='response')
```

Both of the training set and the test set are data.frame.

Comment: Probably when you split your data in train/test sets, some of the variables are factors and some of their classes/levels belong to the test set, but not the train set.

Comment: You do realize that you haven't provided any of your data?? Does `testset2` have all the columns present in `trainset1`? Are they of the same class: `sapply(trainset1.class); sapply(testset2,class)`.

Comment: the testset has more variables than the trainset, I have done that before but R didn't complain, not sure why it's not working this time.

Comment: Did you do that using same type of model or a different one? Did you have variables as factors or as characters?

Comment: I use the same model but a separate set of data, I have variables as character in the trainset, but that's the predicted variable "b", whereas the test set does not have the predicted variable "b", but that shouldn't affect the model because I'm not comparing the result of the testset with the trainset.